# How to properly sort awt colors by hue and saturation

Tags: java, colors, awt

I have a list of colors, I need to sort it as if it is an hsv square (the kind of thing that is used in color pickers), I tried to sort by `Color#getRGB` and by hue and saturation sequentially, but there was always sorting on only one axis (either hue or saturation) and all the other hsv axes were randomly mixed. How can colors be sorted by hsv correctly?
The code below sorts well by color and value, but due to the fact that there is no saturation sorting, white squares appear from time to time

```java
public final static class ColorComparator {
    public static List<Color> sort(List<Color> in, int width, int height) {
            
            Collections.sort(in, (c1,c2) -> {
                var col1 =(Color) c1;
                var col2 = (Color ) c2;
                var cc1 = Color.RGBtoHSB(col1.getRed(),col1.getGreen(),col1.getBlue(),null);
                var cc2 = Color.RGBtoHSB(col2.getRed(),col2.getGreen(),col2.getBlue(),null);
                return Float.valueOf(cc1[0]).compareTo(cc2[0]);
            });
            var k = 0;
            var lists = new ArrayList<Color>();
            for(int i = 0; i<width;i++) {
                var l = new ArrayList<Color>();
                for(int j = 0; j<height; j++) {
                    l.add(in.get(k));
                    k++;
                }
                Collections.sort(l, (c1,c2) -> {
                var col1 =(Color) c1;
                var col2 = (Color ) c2;
                var cc1 = Color.RGBtoHSB(col1.getRed(),col1.getGreen(),col1.getBlue(),null);
                var cc2 = Color.RGBtoHSB(col2.getRed(),col2.getGreen(),col2.getBlue(),null);
                return Float.valueOf(cc1[2]).compareTo(cc2[2]);
            });
            lists.addAll(l);
         }  
       return lists;      
   }      
}
```

Comment: [Maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651781/sort-list-of-colors-by-hsv-hsb), possibly [helpful](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/30/colour-sorting/)

Comment: Unless you show us your code, it's hard for us to guess what you've done wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Normally you sort the hues (colors) on one axis (say across the top), then the saturation on another (say downwards).

Comment: Looks like you're sorting by brightness where you mean to sort by saturation.  Try changing `Float.valueOf(cc1[2]).compareTo(cc2[2])` to `Float.valueOf(cc1[1]).compareTo(cc2[1])`

Comment: I tried this too, instead of black squares, white ones appear